# Combination with Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

- Kate is planning for her $8$ days Study Period.
- Each day she can choose one of the $3$ Subjects: Math, English or
  Physics.
- She never studies Math and English on consecutive days. (i.e.No ME or EM)
- She also wants to study at least all $3$ subjects on at least one day of
  her study period.

How many different schedules are possible?.

I tried $3^4-3 \cdot 2^4+3 \cdot 1= 36$ for $4$ day schedule. I draw the picture and there shall be only $10$ possible schedules. Not sure how to do exclusion on no math and English on consecutive days. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your thoughts on this question..

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Information about what you have attempted should be included in the question rather than being placed in the comments, where it might be missed.

Comment: @GregBrown,To confirm, the point 3, are $MM, EE, ME$ not allowed ?

Comment: @ nyeow Nyeow, Only ME or EM not Allowed. (P.S. I check my picture, there should be Only 8 possible schedule.)

Comment: Is it some coding problem you are doing this?

Comment: @ Kartik Bhatia, No just a math problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is a two step approach based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* and PIE, the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

**Fist step: $A(z)$ avoiding bad words**

We consider the set of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{E,M,P\}$$ and the set $B=\{EM, ME\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $A(z)$ with the coefficient of $z^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $A(z)$  is
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\frac{1}{1-dz-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ being the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[EM])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[ME])
\end{align*}

We also keep track of the used letters which are needed when considering PIE and calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[EM])&=-(EM)z^2-Ez\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[EM])\\\
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[ME])&=-(ME)z^2-Mz\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[ME])\\
\end{align*}
which results in
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[EM])=-EMz^2\frac{1-Ez}{1-EMz^2}\tag{2}\\
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[ME])=-EMz^2\frac{1-Mz}{1-EMz^2}\\
\end{align*}

From (1) and (2) in (1) we obtain the generating function

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A}&\color{blue}{(z;E,M,P)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-(E+M+P)+EMz^2\frac{1-Ez}{1-EMz^2}+EMz^2\frac{1-MZ}{1-EMz^2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1-EMz^2}{1-(E+M+P)z+EMz^2+EMPz^3}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Note that
\begin{align*}
A(z)&=A(z;1,1,1)\\
&=\frac{1-z^2}{1-3z+z^2+z^3}\\
&=1+3z+7z^2+17z^3+41z^4+99z^5\\
&\qquad+239z^6+577z^7+\color{blue}{1\,393}z^8+3\,363z^9+8\,119z^{10}+\cdots
\end{align*}
where the coefficients of $z^n$ give the number of words of length $n$ which do not contain $EM$ or $ME$. These coefficients (calculated with Wolfram Alpha) are in accordance with the numbers stated in @GregBrowns answer.

**Second step: With PIE to $B(z;E,M,P)$**

We are looking for words which contain each of the letters $\{E,M,P\}$ and denote the corresponding generating function $B(z;E,M,P)$. We do so by excluding words which do *not* contain one of these letters using PIE. To get words which do not contain for instance $E$, we calculate
\begin{align*}
[E^0]A(z;E,M,P)=A(z;E,M,P)|_{E=0}
\end{align*}
which we denote as $A(z;0,M,P)$.

Using PIE we calculate $B(z;E,M,P)$ with the help of (3) as
\begin{align*}
B&(z;E,M,P)\\
&=A(z;E,M,P)\\
&\qquad-A(z;0,M,P)-A(z;E,0,P)-A(z;E,M,0)\\
&\qquad+A(z;0,0,P)+A(z;0,M,0)+A(z;E,0,0)\\
&\qquad-A(z;0,0,0)\\
&=\frac{1-EMz^2}{1-(E+M+P)z+EMz^2+EMPz^3}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{1-(M+P)z}-\frac{1}{1-(E+P)z}-\frac{1-EMz^2}{1-(E+M)z+EMz^2}\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{1-Pz} +\frac{1}{1-Mz}+\frac{1}{1-Ez}\\
&\qquad-1\tag{4}\\
\end{align*}

> We finally get the wanted generating function $B(z)$ from (4) as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(z)}&=B(z;1,1,1,1)\\
> &=\frac{1-z^2}{1-3z+z^2+z^3}-\frac{2}{1-2z}-\frac{1-z^2}{1-2z+z^2}+\frac{3}{1-z}-1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+z}{1-2z-z^2}-\frac{2}{1-2z}+\frac{1}{1-z}}\\
> &=2z^3+10z^4+36z^5+112z^6+322z^7+\color{blue}{882}z^8+2\,340z^9+\cdots\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> where the last line was calculated with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

**Result:** There are $\color{blue}{882}$ valid words of length $8$ which do not contain $EM$ and $ME$ and so, that each word contains the three letters $E,M,P$.

---

---

Two plausibility checks: $n=4$ and $n=8$.

- We see in (5) there are $10$ valid words of length $4$. These are
  \begin{align*}
  &\text{EEPM}\quad\text{EPMM}\quad\text{EPMP}\quad\text{EPPM}\quad\text{MMPE}\\
  &\text{MPEE}\quad\text{MPEP}\quad\text{MPPE}\quad\text{PEPM}\quad\text{PMPE}
  \end{align*}
- We manually calculate the coefficient of $z^8$ from (5). We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of a series. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{[z^8]}&\color{blue}{B(z)}=[z^8]\left(\frac{1+z}{1-2z-z^2 }-\frac{2}{1-2z}+\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\\
  &=\left([z^8]+[z^7]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j(2+z)^j-2[z^8]\sum_{j=0}^\infty(2z)^j+[z^8]\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j\\
  &=\sum_{j=0}^8[z^{8-j}](2+z)^j+\sum_{j=0}^7[z^{7-j}](2+z)^j-2(2^8)+1\\
  &=\sum_{j=0}^8\binom{j}{8-j}2^{2j-8}+\sum_{j=0}^7\binom{j}{7-j}2^{2j-7}-2^9+1\\
  &=\binom{4}{4}2^0+\binom{5}{3}2^2+\binom{6}{2}2^4+\binom{7}{1}2^6+\binom{8}{0}2^8\\
  &\qquad+\binom{4}{3}2^1+\binom{5}{2}2^3+\binom{6}{1}2^5+\binom{7}{0}2^7-511\\
  &=1+40+240+448+256\\
  &\qquad+8+80+192+128-511\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=882}
  \end{align*}
  as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I am 8th grade middle school student. I am having difficulty to comprehend your solution.Thank you also for the detailed two plausibility check and it helped me to understand how the equation was derived. I could see the pattern for the 8 days. I could not understand why to deduct 2^9 and add 1 at the end.  Please explain it if possible, thank you.

Comment: @GregBrown: Expanding the  *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* gives $\frac{2}{1-2z}=2\left(1+2z+(2z)^2+\cdots+(2z)^8+\cdots\right)$. We are looking for the coefficient of $[z^8]$ of this series which is $2\cdot 2^8=2^9=512$. This geometric series is a consequence of the principle of inclusion-exclusion. For a first impression of PIE just check the example with sets $A,B,C$ of the related wiki page. The constant $1$ is also a consequence of PIE corresponding to $A(z;0,0,0)$. We obtain $2^9-1=512-1=511$

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the question. I still cannot fully comprehend your answer, however, your answer help me find a primitive way to answer this question. I find the total scenarios without ME and EM for each day, then took away where only 2 subjects were in the schedule and plus 1 for undercounting.

Comment: Day 8,
M 408,
E 408,
P 577,
Total Scenarios 1393,
Take Away Only 2 subjects s in the schedule  =2*2^8=512, then
+1 for undercounting   882

Comment: @GregBrown: You're welcome! Since you derived an answer by your own efforts, you might want to also present it to the community and add it as an additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Day1, if P chosen, then all 3 (P, M, E) on Day 2. If she chose M, then she only has 2 (P,M) on day 2 and if she chose  E she also only has 2  (P, E) for day 2. Add up all the possibilities she has total 7 cases for day 2.

In day 3 and in all of the scenarios on the day 2, she can do P, so she has 3+2+2=7 options. If she chose E she has 3+2=5 and the same for M. Adds all possibility for Day 3 is 17.

```
Day 1   Day 2   Day 3   Day 4   Day 5   Day 6   Day 7    Day 8
```

M   1   2   5   12  29  70  169 408

E   1   2   5   12  29  70  169 408

P   1   3   7   17  41  99  239 577

**Total**3  7   17  41  99  239 577 **1393**

**Take Away** not all 3 subjects in the schedule = 2*2^8(number of days)= **512**

**Add 1** for undercounting

**882**

Comment: Congrats! Very nice solution. I've added a small section at the end of the first part in my answer, which confirms your numbers calculated in Totals. (+1)

Comment: Since $2\cdot 2^8=512$ you might want to write "and add $1$ for undercounting $882$" instead of $+1$ which invalidates the identity $2\cdot 2^8=512$. Since you found a very nice answer by yourself, you are also free of course to accept your own answer. Regards,

Comment: Nice approach. +1

Comment: @ Markus Scheuer Thank you for for add the section and it help me understand your method further.

Comment: @ RobPratt Thank you for put my method into formulas. It is a more sophisticated way to present the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive approach.  For $d \in \{0, \dots, 8\}$, $m \in \{0,1\}$, $e \in \{0,1\}$, $p \in \{0,1\}$, $s \in \{.,\text{M},\text{E},\text{P}\}$, let $f(d,m,e,p,s)$ be the number of schedules, given $d$ days remaining, $m$ required days of Math remaining, $e$ required days of English remaining, $p$ required days of Physics remaining, and previous subject $s$.  Then
$$f(d,m,e,p,s) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $d < m + e + p$} \\
1 & \text{if $d = 0$} \\
[s \not= \text{E}] f(d-1,\max(m-1,0),e,p,\text{M})\\
+ [s \not= \text{M}] f(d-1,m,\max(e-1,0),p,\text{E})\\
+ f(d-1,m,e,\max(p-1,0),\text{P})
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
If $d<m+e+p$, there are not enough days left to satisfy the requirement of all subjects. Otherwise, if $d=0$, there is only the empty schedule. Otherwise, the allowable choices of the current subject depend on the previous subject $s$, and whichever subject is chosen reduces the days remaining by $1$ and the requirement for that subject by $1$ unless the requirement has already been met. The brackets $[]$ are Iverson notation that yields $1$ if the expression is true and $0$ if the expression is false.
We want to compute $f(8,1,1,1,.)$, which turns out to be $882$.

By the way, $f(4,1,1,1,.)=10 \not= 8$.

---

Because the required number of days for each subject is $1$, you  could instead let $g(d,S,s)$ be the number of schedules, given $d$ days remaining, $S\subseteq\{\text{M},\text{E},\text{P}\}$ subset of subjects remaining, and previous subject $s$.  Then
$$g(d,S,s) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $d < |S|$} \\
1 & \text{if $d = 0$} \\
[s \not= \text{E}] g(d-1,S\setminus \{\text{M}\},\text{M})\\
+ [s \not= \text{M}] g(d-1,S\setminus \{\text{E}\},\text{E})\\
+ g(d-1,S\setminus \{\text{P}\},\text{P})
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g(8,\{\text{M},\text{E},\text{P}\},.)=882$.

---

Here's a formalization of the first part of @GregBrown's approach, ignoring the requirement to study each subject at least once.
Let $m_n$ (and $e_n$ and $p_n$) be the number of schedules of length $n$ that end in $M$ (and $E$ and $P$, respectively) and do not contain $ME$ or $EM$.  Then $m_1=e_1=p_1=1$, $m_2=e_2=2$, $p_2=3$, and for $n\ge 3$ we have
\begin{align}
m_n &= m_{n-1} + p_{n-1} \tag1\\
e_n &= e_{n-1} + p_{n-1} \tag2\\
p_n &= m_{n-1} + e_{n-1} + p_{n-1} \tag3
\end{align}
Now let $t_n=m_n+e_n+p_n$ be the number of schedules of length $n$ that do not contain $ME$ or $EM$, and note that summing $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ implies that
$$t_n=2t_{n-1}+p_{n-1}=2t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}.$$  By using this recurrence and the initial conditions $t_1=3$ and $t_2=7$, we find that
\begin{align}
t_3 &= 2t_2 + t_1 = 2(7)+3=17 \\
t_4 &= 2t_3 + t_2 = 2(17)+7=41 \\
t_5 &= 2t_4 + t_3 = 2(41)+17=99 \\
t_6 &= 2t_5 + t_4 = 2(99)+41=239 \\
t_7 &= 2t_6 + t_5 = 2(239)+99=577 \\
t_8 &= 2t_7 + t_6 = 2(577)+239=1393 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for answering the questions with simple recursive approach. I am 8th Grade middle school student and I do not understand your solution. Do you have any simpler explanation for me or simpler way to calculate it? Thank you!

Comment: @GregBrown I added more explanation just now.

Comment: @RobPratt: Clever approach, using Iverson brackets to avoid forbidden patterns and using flags for $M$, $E$ and $P$ to guarantee that each letter occurs at least once.  (+1)

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the question. I still cannot fully comprehend your answer, however, your answer help me find a primitive way to answer this question. I find the total scenarios without ME and EM for each day, then took away where only 2 subjects were in the schedule and plus 1 for undercounting.

Comment: Day 8,
M 408,
E 408,
P 577,
Total Scenarios 1393,
Take Away Only 2 subjects s in the schedule  =2*2^8=512, then
+1 for undercounting   882